# View is not changing in SwiftUI when user is logged in

Tags: swift, api, swiftui

I have a small problem. Im making a post request to log in, the "authenticated" is set to "true" when the request is succesful but the view is not changing.

When i'm pressing the Log In button, i'm calling this function :

```
 @Published var authenticatedAngajator = false

    func postAuthAngajator(email: String, password: String) {
        guard let url = URL(string: postUrl) else { return }

        let body: [String: Any] = ["email": email, "password": password, "acctype" : "angajator"]

        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.httpBody = body.percentEncoded()
        request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
            guard let data = data else { return }
            let resData = try! JSONDecoder().decode(ServerMessage.self, from: data)
            print(resData.result)
            if resData.result == "success" {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.authenticatedAngajator = true
                }
               
            }
        }.resume()
    }
```

And this is my content view, but when the request is called, the view is not changing and i do not know why. This is my content view  :

```
struct ContentView: View {
  
    @EnvironmentObject var userAuth : HttpAuth
    var body: some View {
       
       if userAuth.authenticatedNevazator {
            MainViewNevazator()
        }
        if userAuth.authenticatedAngajator {
            MainViewAngajator()
        }
        if userAuth.authenticatedUniversitate {
            MainViewUniversitate()
        }
        else
        {
            MainView()
        }
        
            }
        }
```

This is where postAuthAngajator is called.

```
struct LoginViewNevazator: View {
    
    @State var emailNevazator: String = ""
    @State var passwordNevazator: String = ""
    @ObservedObject var manager = HttpAuth()
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ZStack {
            VStack {
                UserImage()
                UsernameTextField(username: $emailNevazator)
                PasswordSecureField(password: $passwordNevazator)
                Button(action: {
                    manager.postAuthNevazator(email: self.emailNevazator, password: self.passwordNevazator)
                }) {
                    LoginButtonContent()
                }
```

What can i do in this situation ?

Comment: You aren't showing enough code to reproduce this issue. For example, in your first `if` case, as long as `authenticatedNevazator`, it will never reach the next `else` case. But, there's not reference to `authenticatedNevazator` anywhere else in your code you've shown. Also, you probably want to stop using `return` and `AnyView()` inside of the `var body` and let the ViewBuilder do all of the work.

Comment: Are you sure your `self.authenticatedAngajator` is referenced to as a StateObject or ObservedObject? If not, your changes to the parameter in the structure that holds that variable, are not observed in your ContextView.

Comment: what does your `print(resData.result)` show? Probably "success", but you test 
on "succes" with one `s`

Comment: @workingdog I modified now to equal = "success" and is working fine

Comment: @jnpdx im using else because i have 3 types of log in

Comment: It's fine to *use* else, but you're comparing two different things: `userAuth.authenticatedNevazator` and `userAuth.authenticatedAngajator`. If the first is always true, the second won't be hit. See WWDC 2021 "Demystifying SwiftUI" for why using `AnyView` can lead to poor performance and unexpected results.

Comment: @jnpdx i've made some changes, yes, on of the problem was the "succes", but the view is still not changing and i do not know why

Comment: Where is `postAuthAngajator` called? Are you sure it's the *same instance* of `HttpAuth`? It's helpful if you provide enough code for a [mre]

Comment: @jnpdx I've just edited the question, you can check

Comment: @Exal unfortunately, that isn't a [mre]. It's not clear how `LoginViewNevazator` is related to `ContentView` at all. It's still unclear where `authenticatedNevazator` and `authenticatedUniversitate` are coming from. And, it's not clear where `@EnvironmentObject var userAuth : HttpAuth` is injected and if it's the same instance as when you called `postAuthAngajator`. We need to be able to see how the code is connected. Ideally, your example would be something that could be copied and pasted into Xcode and would compile.

Comment: In `LoginViewNevazator` (and all the other similar Views), you are creating a new
`HttpAuth()` not using the single source of truth. So 
try replacing `@ObservedObject var manager = HttpAuth()` with 
`@EnvironmentObject var manager: HttpAuth`.